# Mockito. How to mock abstract method call in class under test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have Test class for controller. I need to inject autowired field. And mock method of Controller's super class (I have no possibility to refactor this situation)

```
   public class ControllerTest {

        @Mock
        Service service;


        @InjectMocks
        Controller controller;


    @Test
    public vois test() {
      controller.process();

    }
}
```

In process() method service is called and superclass's method, too.

I tried to init my controller in test in this way

```
new Controller() {

@Override
superMethod() {
    //do nothing
}
}
```

But I cannot inject service mock in this case due to setter is missing. I can do it with reflection, but maybe someone knows more elegant solution?

Comment: Mocking methods of super classes changes the behavior of the object you want to test. So this really sounds like something you shouldn't do at all.

Comment: Although this definitely looks like a smell, however if you have to do the operation you mention, have you tried using a Mockito Spy? I mean something like `Controller spy = new Mockito.spy(controller);` `doNothing().when(spy).process()`; Let me know how it goes

Comment: I tried to use spy. But I need to inject service mock somehow in controller. Also if I've created one more controller (spy) I've got NPE somewhere in when statement

Comment: You could use only the spy and then use Spring's `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` to set the mock dependency

Answer (score 0):

If you are using annotations, you must to put @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) above the ControllerTest or create setUp method like this:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Hope this help.